# Can't find "Embed dashboard" in Superset

Tags: docker-compose, embed, apache-superset

I'm going to embed the Superset dashboard into ReactJs. When I login using the default admin user I can't find the words "**Embed dashboard**" in the dashboard dropdown that I'm currently opening. Previously I've changed some settings in **config.py** Superset

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
"EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True
CORS_OPTIONS = {
  'supports_credentials': True,
  'allow_headers': ['*'],
  'resources':['*'],
  'origins': ['http://localhost:8088', 'http://localhost:8888']
}
```

and **docker-compose.yaml**, after setting i'm restart docker container

```
version: '3'
services:
  superset:
    image: apache/superset:latest
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    container_name: superset
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../data/superset:/opt/superset/workspace
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Jakarta
      - SUPERSET_FEATURE_EMBEDDED_SUPERSET='true'
```

like this display on my dashboard

[image]

How do I get the "**Embed dashboard**" message to appear? Are there any mistakes in the settings?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset

> Enable Superset Embed Dashboard Feature
> If you go to dashboard options, there is no embed dashboard option. To enable it, open superset_config.py (located inside docker/pythonpath_dev) - this file allows you to configure superset and add the following feature flag:
>
> ```
> FEATURE_FLAGS = {..., "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True}
> ```

Comment: In addition to this, the user account required some of these permissions: "can read on EmbeddedDashboard", "can delete embedded on Dashboard", "can set embedded on Dashboard", "can get embedded on Dashboard".